# Issue with globalCompositeOperation and setTimeout

Tags: javascript, canvas, globalcompositeoperation

I am trying to create an animation that clears(like an eraser) a rectangular fill on top of an image. As the circle animates, it clears away all the area it has covered.

I am able to do so with the globalCompositeOperation, however when I try to slow down the animation, it does not work. I am trying setTimeout function. Any ideas why the animation is not slowing down? I have tried everything I know, any help or alternatives would be greatly appreciated.

Also when I try to use the setTimeout(func(),time in ms) function it removes the image as well.

```
function compose()
//adds the purple fill rectangle, adds the image and then animates the circle
{
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
fillRectangle(100, 100, 900, 500);
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
context.drawImage(img, destX, destY);
for (var a = 0; a < 1000; a++) {

    if (x + dx + radius > width || x + dx < radius) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if (y + dy + radius > height || y + dy < radius) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    x = x + dx;
    y = y + dy;
    //setTimeout("circle(x,y)", 1);
    circle(x, y);
    }
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
context.drawImage(img, destX, destY
}
function circle(x, y)
{// this simply animates the circle over the purple fill
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
context.fillStyle = "#444444";
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
context.closePath();
context.fill(); //setTimeout("context.fill();",3);
context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
}
```

Full Code:

Canvas Test

```
        var t;
        //holds the drawing context of the canvas element
        var context;

        //size of canvas
        var width = 600;
        var height = 300;

        //position of the ball
        var x = 150;
        var y = 150;

        //speed of the ball
        var dx = 2;
        var dy = 2;

        //ball radius
        var radius = 10;
        var compositeType = ['xor'];
        var destX = 0;
        var destY = 0;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = 'nexus.jpg';
        function init() {
            context = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

            compose();

        }
        function compose()
        //adds the purple fill rectangle, adds the image and then animates the circle
        {
            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
            fillRectangle(0, 0, 900, 600);
            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
            context.drawImage(img, destX, destY);
            var cnt = 0;

            function runIteration() {
                if (x + dx + radius > width || x + dx < radius) {
                    dx = -dx;
                }
                if (y + dy + radius > height || y + dy < radius) {
                    dy = -dy;
                }
                x = x + dx;
                y = y + dy;
                circle(x, y);
                cnt++;
                if (cnt < 10000) {
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, destX, destY);
                    setTimeout(runIteration, 10);

                }
            }
            runIteration();

        }

        function fillRectangle(x, y, w, h)
        {
            context.fillStyle = "#550055";
            context.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        }
        //draws the circle with center location at x,y
        function circle(x, y) {
            // context.globalAlpha=0.1;
            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';

            context.fillStyle = "#444444";
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
            context.closePath();
            context.fill(); //setTimeout("context.fill();",3);

            context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
        }

        //draws a rectangle with width(w) & height(h) with top left corner at (x,y)
        function rectangle(x, y, w, h) {
            context.fillStyle = "#000000";
            context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
        }
        //clears the whole canvas
        function clear() {
            context.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 300);
        }
        window.addEventListener("load", init, true);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `setTimeout()` isn't the proper way to do things.  `setTimeout()` is an asychronous function.  It returns immediately and schedules it's work for later.

As your code is written, the entire for loop will run immediately, setting 1000 `setTimeout` timers.  This won't slow down the animation, only delay it's start slightly.

To slow the animation down, you will have to restructure your code such that you execute each iteration of the for loop in a `setTimeout()` and when that timeout finishes and executes, you then schedule the next `setTimeout()` with the next iteration of the loop.  It would go something like this:

```
function compose()
//adds the purple fill rectangle, adds the image and then animates the circle
{
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    fillRectangle(100, 100, 900, 500);
    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
    context.drawImage(img, destX, destY);
    var cnt = 0;

    function runIteration() {
        if (x + dx + radius > width || x + dx < radius) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
        if (y + dy + radius > height || y + dy < radius) {
            dy = -dy;
        }
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
        circle(x, y);
        cnt++;
        if (cnt < 1000) {
            setTimeout(runIteration, 10);
        }
    }
    runIteration();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I had tried something similar to this before and I had the animation working. However, this way causes one problem. This completely erases everything from the canvas, when I want the image to stay but the rectangle to get erased. I tried moving the drawImage after the runIteration and with that the first circle it draws removes the rectangular fill and not the image. However, any subsequent circles after that remove the image and rectangular fill revealing the empty canvas.

Comment: I actually just tried something and it is working, I put the draw image right before setTimeout function in the code you provided and it worked. Any help on why  this works in this scenario would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: I'd have to see the entire code you're using (you could add it as a new revision at the end of your question) to comment on what you have.  The important issue is that you can't run anything after the animation until the last setTimeout runs.

Comment: Here is the complete code. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8075092/667509 I was not sure how else to put the new code.

Comment: I don't know why you started a new question.  I think it would have been more appropriate to use the Edit link below your original question and add this new version to the end of your post.